# Entity framework activates trigger to other database: error

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a ASP.NET web application which does some changes on a table in SQL Server 2008 R2.
On this table there is a trigger that does updates on another table in another database on the same database server.

When saving the changes I'm having the following error: 
- The error message: The underlying provider failed on Commit.
- InnerException: This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable.

Also allowing the database user to connect to the other database isn't working.

Somebody knows how I can make this work?

Comment: Step 1 - find whoever implemented this trigger and hurt them. Triggers should *not* access external resources (and in this case, another database is an external resource, even if it's on the same instance).

Comment: Step 1 done. Which is the best approach to keep the databases in sync? MS Sync framework or replication services?

Comment: If it's synchronizing databases, yes, replication of some sort might be indicated. If it's updating/auditing related data, you might consider something like service broker.

Answer (score 0):

The trigger is not related to Entity Framework.

The trigger fires when changes are made to the table irrespective of where that change came from.

This is probably a rights issue, the system is attempting to make the change to the second database with the security context that was used to connect to the first database. It the change that was caused by the trigger fails, then everything in the same transaction will fail.

Since you are accessing 2 databases in a transaction, you are using MSDTC, make sure that it is started and that you have rights to it.